# Вживання прийменника "по" у словосполученнях "по дружбі", "по пам'яті"

Tags: вживання-слів, прийменники

Чи правильно буде вживати прийменник "по" у словосполученнях "по пам'яті" у наступних реченнях:

"Зайшов ось... по старій пам'яті. Діватися більше нікуди." (рос. "Зашёл вот... по старой памяти. Деваться больше некуда.").

На сайті [OnlineCorrector](https://onlinecorrector.com.ua/uk/%D0%BF%D0%BE/) знайшов деякі приклади заміни прийменника "по", і мені здається, що буде правильно використати "у", що в результаті дасть наступне речення: "Зайшов ось... у старій пам'яті. Діватися більше нікуди."

Також цікавить як виглядатиме словосполучення "по дружбі", приклад: "Приходь, покажу по дружбі." Чи правильно використовувати прийменник "по" тут також?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Роблячи запит [`[tag="prep.*"] [lemma="старий"] [lemma="пам'ять"]`](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%5Btag=%22prep.*%22%5D+%5Blemma=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%5D+%5Blemma=%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%27%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%22%5D) у [ГРАК](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8)-10, я бачу лише два варіанти:

- *по старій пам'яті* (здебільшого);
- *за старою пам'яттю* (рідше).

(Трапляння *у старій пам'яті* там є, але лише одне й у іншому контексті.) Отже раджу використовувати *по старій пам'яті* й *за старою пам'яттю*.

Я не спеціаліст, але, наскільки я знаю, *[по](http://sum.in.ua/s/po)* — загалом прийнятний прийменник української мови. Наскільки я знаю, його замінюють на щось інше в трьох випадках: (1) коли його було помилково вжито в ролі, яка йому в українській мові не притаманна (а притаманна, наприклад, у російській); (2) коли його було вжито в ролі, яка йому справді притаманна, але є й інші способи висловлення думки, про які, на жаль, часто несправедливо забувають (тобто його вживання не було помилкою, але краще врізноманітнити мовлення, ніж завжди піддаватися одному й тому самому варіанту); (3) просто за інерцією (гіперпуризм). Навіть сторінка OnlineCorrector, на яку Ви посилаєтеся, наводить деякі приклади, де *по* було б доречне (а не лише приклади, де, на їхню думку, його краще замінити).